# Select HTML element with a string

Tags: javascript, html, json

Is it possible to make a reference to a html element by a string (preferably a query selector), i made a mouse tracker which should add the target element, but if you reload the page it should still be able to find the same element.
i tried going with `event.composedPath()`
and `event.target`, But both dont seem to work

the string will be saved in a json file

Comment: Are you asking how to get a query selector string from an existing element?

Comment: If the element has an ID, you can just use `'#' + element.id`

Comment: thats what im asking yes, but none of the elements has a class or id, the string can be any element getting hovered or clicked on

Comment: its basically an empty `div` or `label` or any other tag

Comment: See the linked question.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, looked my ass off for that :D